# Node Promise Resolve Not Exiting Function

Tags: node.js, promise

I am trying to create a node promise to accept HTTP connections every 1 second or timeout after 20 seconds.

When the function is wrapped in a promise and returned with resolve() or reject() the function does not stop or exit properly.

```
var lMain = true;
setInterval(function(){
    lMain=true;
}, 1000);

async function acceptConnection(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        if(lMain){
            lMain=false;
            console.log('connection accept');
            return resolve();
        }
        console.log("Defer connection..");
        

    var lTimeout=setTimeout(() => {return reject(new Error(`Accept Connection Timed out (20000)`));}, 20000);
    var lInterval=setInterval(() => {
        if(lMain){
            lMain=false;
            clearTimeout(lTimeout);
            clearInterval(lInterval);
            console.log('connection accept2');
            return resolve();
        }
        
        console.log("Defer connection2..");
        
    }, 500);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log('AcceptConnection Error: '+err);
    
});
```

I am attempting to use this in my requestListener like:

```
const requestListener = async function (req, res){  
if(await !acceptConnection()){
    return res.writeHead(200).end('Too many connections.');
}
...
```

What am I doing wrong? I am very new to Node and any explanation would be awesome!

Expected Results are:

```
connection accept
Defer connection..
Defer connection2..
Defer connection2..
connection accept2
```

The below answer with the clear timeouts was my problem, not understanding how resolve and reject works and having await for a promise. Having the await promise seems to have causes a "double connection".

```
acceptConnection().then(() => {
    console.log('connection accepted');
}).catch(() =>{
    console.log('connection rejected');
});
```

Comment: you are not clearing the interval and timeout

Comment: Once the promise resolves, won't those automatically clear? (I didn't see any changes so far trying to use those). 

When I set the first return resolve();  - I am unclear why it's going to console.log("Defer connection.."); and starting the setTimeout

Comment: Thats right it wont clear those timeout and intervals.

Comment: When you call `return resolve();` inside the if block, it only resolves the Promise and immediately continues with the rest of the code inside the Promise constructor. That's why you still see the execution of `console.log("Defer connection..")` and the`setTimeout`

Comment: ohhhh, so you can resolve or reject the promise and still continue with code from the original? Cool. That makes me "think of it differently". How do you "exit" the promise? By returning an error ? What if it's resolved good?

Comment: When you `resolve()` a promise, it succeeded, and code continues in `.then();` when you `reject()`, it's an error, and code goes to `.catch()`. You don't exit the promise; outside code keeps running after a promise settles.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use a combination of Promises, setInterval, and setTimeout in a way that might be causing unexpected behavior. Here's a simplified version of your code with the necessary corrections:

```
let lMain = true;

setInterval(function () {
    lMain = true;
}, 1000);

async function acceptConnection() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        if (lMain) {
            lMain = false;
            console.log('connection accept');
            resolve();
        } else {
            console.log("Defer connection..");

            var lTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
                clearInterval(lInterval); // Clear the interval if the timeout occurs
                reject(new Error(`Accept Connection Timed out (20000)`));
            }, 20000);

            var lInterval = setInterval(() => {
                if (lMain) {
                    lMain = false;
                    clearInterval(lInterval); // Clear the interval if the connection is accepted
                    clearTimeout(lTimeout); // Clear the timeout as well
                    console.log('connection accept2');
                    resolve();
                } else {
                    console.log("Defer connection2..");
                }
            }, 500);
        }
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log('AcceptConnection Error: ' + err);
    });
}
```

Comment: Yours works. I can't spot the difference besides the }else{ for the main loop. Is that all you changed? And the clear intervals.

Comment: In your original question there were no clear Intervals and timeouts

Comment: 1. **Clearing Intervals and Timeouts:** I added `clearInterval` and `clearTimeout` calls at the appropriate places to ensure that intervals and timeouts are cleared when the conditions are met. This prevents them from continuing to run unnecessarily.

2. **`else` Block:** I added an `else` block to handle the scenario where `lMain` is initially `false`. In this case, the deferred connection logic is triggered along with setting up the intervals and timeouts.